# Is a creature that sees a Medusa's eyes automatically subjected to a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Famously, the gaze of a *Medusa's* eyes turns hapless adventurers to stone.

However, is this save automatic upon seeing her eyes?

The [**Medusa**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/medusa)'s Petrifying Gaze feature says (emphasis mine):

> ***Petrifying Gaze.*** When a creature that can see the medusa's eyes starts its turn within 30 feet of the medusa, the medusa **can** force it to make a DC 14 Constitution saving throw if the medusa isn't incapacitated and can see the creature.

Emphasis mine.

The text states that the Medusa **can** force the creature to make a save, implying that the Medusa chooses when this effect takes place. Is this how it works, or is the effect automatic?

For a little more background, currently I am running

> *Tomb of Annihilation*, where *Zalkoré* has her face hidden behind a translucent veil.

The players can clearly see her eyes, but she hasn't yet decided to activate her ability yet, so no petrification saving throws yet. Am I playing this correctly, RAW?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No, it's up to the Medusa

You've quoted the relevant requirement in that that the [Medusa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/medusa) *can* force the creature to make the saving throw. If the Medusa opts not to, then no saving throw is needed.

### Yes, you are playing this correctly.

Your decision to not force the save until you are ready to do so was the right one.